# How do I start a new Ionic 4 app without using Angular? With Vue.js or Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, ionic-framework, vue.js, ionic4, ionic-cli

I am getting started with Ionic 4, and wondering how to start a new app without using Angular? The guide [mentions](https://ionicframework.com/docs/building/starting) [ionic start](https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/commands/start/) for this, as in `ionic start [name] [template]` but this creates a scaffolding set up for Angular. I think I saw a video explaining how to use non-Angular but can’t find it again now. I’m looking to use Vue or no framework.

Comment: I used to think Ionic 4 was all about ditching Angular and instead using custom elements?

Comment: No it still has tight integration, but it’s now optional, so other frameworks or vanilla can be used. The docs still haven’t been fully updated though, so still only talk about Angular in some places.

Comment: I've posted your question on the Ionic team slack for you.

Comment: https://blog.ionicframework.com/a-vue-from-ionic/ includes how to get started with Vue and Ionic. Basically just `npm install @ionic/vue`.

Comment: If you have not done much with Ionic yet and maybe want to switch, you could have a look at [quasar](https://quasar-framework.org/) which offers native Apps and electron support, too.<br>
A big difference here is that it completly works with VueJS, so if you never want to use Angular this could be the by far easier method. Here is the [Getting started](https://quasar-framework.org/guide/introduction-to-quasar.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understand the README, if you are looking for an Ionic Vue application, at this time, you should first create a project with Vue and then add Ionic.

Copy/paste of the [Ionic's Vue README](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic/tree/master/vue):

> To get started simply install `@ionic/vue` and `@ionic/core` with npm into your project and then register @ionic/vue as a plugin to your vue application.

So first:

```
npm install @ionic/vue @ionic/core --save
```

and then as described in the README:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Ionic from '@ionic/vue';
Vue.use(Ionic);

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app');
```

I didn't tried but it's what I would try ;)

Comment: Thanks David, so currently `ionic start` only supports Angular then.

Comment: I'm not sure but I would that today (February 2019) yes. But in the future, I would say no respectively the CLI might support others too, but that's only my guess. See for type of project for example: https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/blob/b1ecd77efeea1d8c5786fd5b042da458d51bc0bd/packages/ionic/src/constants.ts#L8

Comment: Not an answer, but if interested, I also wrote an article about how to add Ionic in any projects respectively without framework too ;) https://medium.com/@david.dalbusco/using-ionic-without-any-frameworks-775dc757e5e8

Comment: Cool, my pleasure